# Using jquery fetching data from DB and filling the dropdowns

Tags: jquery

I have three dropdowns say "country" , "state" , "city".
The items of country dropdown should get fetched from db.
And the state dropdown items should also fetched from DB according to country selection.
I need this to be done in Jquery.
Can anyone help out??

Comment: can you post some code what you have tried that will make us able to help you batter

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.post` or `.get` functions to retrieve data from a server-side script. Your server-side script will have to query the database and return the required data.

You can add a `change` event to the dropdown (I'm assuming it's a `select` element) and fire a `.post` or `.get` request in the event handler.

It's difficult to help you in any more detail than that without seeing what you've already got and what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using the better-half of a website, the serverside, You need to call a Server-side script like a `.php` file to execute the DB queries and then echo the result to the Client-side, you can make ajax calls to the script to fetch the data and load it into a `Select` DOM tag.